# Online IDE with an Ubuntu workspace?

Tags: application-development, workspaces, window, ide

Are there any online IDEs out there that have a Linux compiler and/or Ubuntu/Linux workspace?

I often work away from home on Linux projects, and usually on Windows PCs, so it'd be great if I could manage to test out my projects online; if I can't manage do so locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a great one:

[Cloud9](https://c9.io/?redirect=0)

> Cloud9 combines a powerful online code editor with a full Ubuntu workspace in the cloud

You can install Linux software, edit files from the built-in terminal, use the interactive Python IDE and perhaps other stuff I haven't yet found out **=)**

You can find out a little more [here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/07/31/cloud-9-ide-now-runs-ubuntu-containers-via-docker/).

Comment: nice, is the workspace using `14.04`? how to configure versions ?

Comment: its very useful for me :)